# Is it possible to simulate SSH remote port forwarding with socat alone?

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, socat

Consider the following scenario.

- Server A has access to serverX:9000.
- Server A has access to serverB:7000.
- Server B is not able to directly access ports on Server A.
- Server B wants access to serverX:9000 but does not have direct access.

The classical way to solve this is with ssh port forwarding.

```
ssh -R 9000:serverX:9000 serverB -p 7000
```

Suppose that, instead of running sshd on serverB and ssh on serverA, I wanted to run non-authenticated network utilities such as `socat` or `nc` on both and solve the same problem.

**Is it possible to achieve remote port forwarding using socat/nc alone, without ssh?**

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with Socat by building a TCP gender changer.

On serverB runs a double listener that waits for connection on 9000 and then forks a sub process that waits for connection on 7000 and finally forwards traffic:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:9000,reuseaddr,fork TCP-LISTEN:7000,reuseaddr
```

On serverA runs a double client that continuously tries to connect to serverB:7000 and on success establishes forwarding to serverX:9000. Note that this generates permanent network traffic, produces logs on firewalls, and is not encrypted:

```
socat TCP:serverB:7000,forever,interval=1,fork TCP:serverX:9000
```

Connections are forwarded with delay, you can control maximum wait time with the interval setting (seconds, float number)

Comment: Will this mechanism allow multiple simultaneous connections to serverX:9000, or only a single connection at a time?

Comment: This allows multiple simultaneous connections. Connections that are already established work without delay.